# jsTree Node Expand/Collapse

Tags: jstree

I ran into the excellent jstree jQuery UI plug in this morning.  In a word - great!  It is easy to use, easy to style & does what it says on the box.  The one thing I have not yet been able to figure out is this - in my app I want to ensure that only one node is expanded at any given time.  i.e. when the user clicks on the + button and expands a node, any previously expanded node should silently be collapsed.  I need to do this in part to prevent the container div for a rather lengthy tree view from creating an ugly scrollbar on overflow and also to avoid "choice overload" for the user.

I imagine that there is some way of doing this but the good but rather terse jstree documentation has not helped me to identify the right way to do this.  I would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jsTree is great but its documentation is rather dense. I eventually figured it out so here is the solution for anyone running into this thread.

Firstly, you need to bind the open_node event to the tree in question.  Something along the lines of

```js
$("tree").jstree({"themes":objTheme,"plugins":arrPlugins,"core":objCore}).
bind("open_node.jstree",function(event,data){closeOld(data)});
```

i.e. you configure the treeview instance and then bind the open_node event.  Here I am calling the closeOld function to do the job I require - close any other node that might be open.  The function goes like so

```js
function closeOld(data)
{
    var nn = data.rslt.obj;
    var thisLvl = nn;
    var levels = new Array();
    var iex = 0;
    while (-1 != thisLvl)
    {
        levels.push(thisLvl);
        thisLvl = data.inst._get_parent(thisLvl);
        iex++;
    }

    if (0 < ignoreExp)
    {
        ignoreExp--;
        return;
    }

    $("#divElements").jstree("close_all");
    ignoreExp = iex;
    var len = levels.length - 1;
    for (var i=len;i >=0;i--) $('#divElements').jstree('open_node',levels[i]);
}
```

This will correctly handle the folding of all other nodes irrespective of the nesting level of the node that has just been expanded.

A brief explanation of the steps involved

- First we step back up the treeview until we reach a top level node (-1 in jstree speak) making sure that we record every ancestor node encountered in the process in the array **levels**
- Next we collapse all the nodes in the treeview
- We are now going to re-expand all of the nodees in the **levels** array.  Whilst doing so we do not want this code to execute again.  To stop that from happening we set the global **ignoreEx** variable to the number of nodes in **levels**
- Finally, we step through the nodes in **levels** and expand each one of them

Answer (score 2):

The above answer will construct tree again and again.
The below code will open the node and collapse which are already opened and it does not construct tree again.

```
.bind("open_node.jstree",function(event,data){
        closeOld(data);
        });
```

and closeOld function contains:

```
function closeOld(data)
{
    if($.inArray(data.node.id, myArray)==-1){
            myArray.push(data.node.id);
            if(myArray.length!=1){
                var arr =data.node.id+","+data.node.parents;
                var res = arr.split(",");
                var parentArray = new Array();
                var len = myArray.length-1;
                for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    parentArray.push(res[i]);
                }
                for (var i=len;i >=0;i--){
                    var index = $.inArray(myArray[i], parentArray);
                if(index==-1){
                    if(data.node.id!=myArray[i]){
                    $('#jstree').jstree('close_node',myArray[i]);
                        delete myArray[i];
                    }
                }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another example for jstree 3.3.2.
It uses [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) lib, feel free to adapt solution to jquery or vanillla js.

```
$(function () {
    var tree = $('#tree');
    tree.on('before_open.jstree', function (e, data) {
        var remained_ids = _.union(data.node.id, data.node.parents);
        var $tree = $(this);
        _.each(
                $tree
                    .jstree()
                    .get_json($tree, {flat: true}),
                function (n) {
                    if (
                        n.state.opened &&
                        _.indexOf(remained_ids, n.id) == -1
                    ) {
                        grid.jstree('close_node', n.id);
                    }
                }
        );
    });
    tree.jstree();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved that by just using the event "before_open" and close all nodes, my tree had just one level tho, not sure if thats what you need.

```
$('#dtree').on('before_open.jstree', function(e, data){
    $("#dtree").jstree("close_all");
});
```